# Данные не записываюся в типизированный файл

Tags: файлы, delphi-7

Такая штука:Пишу прогу на Delphi7.Есть 3 Unit'а и 3 формы.
Программа введет некую базу данных.На форме1 есть кнопки:Добавить и Просмотреть.
(unit2)Первая кнопка записывает данные в типизированный файл(Record),(unit3)Вторая считывает и дает пользователю просмотреть все записи.Так вот все работает,но с задержкой,
например:добавил запись,нажимаю кнопку просмотреть-а там ничего.Но если закрыть прогу и потом просмотреть запись появится.Будто запись где -то висит а после выключения программы она записывается в файл. 
   //Unit2

```
If MessageDlg ('Подтвердите действие', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo] ,0) = mrYes then
 begin
  assignFile(f,'C:\Users\11\Desktop\ÓïðàæíåíèÿDelphi\DElaDB\HADB1.txt');//связали
  reset(f);//открыли
  qr.name1:=a1;
  qr.chto1:=a;
  qr.kogda:=s;
  seek(f,FileSize(f));//переместили чтоб в конец добавлялась запись
  write(f,qr);//записали
  MessageDlg ('Записано', mtConfirmation,[mbOk] ,0);
  CloseFile(f);//Закрыли
 end
else exit;

end;
  //перед открытием формы проверим файл
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
if FileExists('C:\Users\11\Desktop\ÓïðàæíåíèÿDelphi\DElaDB\HADB4.txt') then
  ShowMessage('Файл есть')
else
  ShowMessage('Файла нет');
```

//unit3  Хочу считать

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.ScrollBars:=ssVertical;
if FileExists('C:\Users\11\Desktop\ÓïðàæíåíèÿDelphi\DElaDB\HADB1.txt') then
 begin
  ShowMessage('Есть');
  assignFile(f1,'C:\Users\11\Desktop\ÓïðàæíåíèÿDelphi\DElaDB\HADB1.txt');//связали
  reset(f1);//открыли
  Label1.Caption:='FS='+IntToStr(FileSize(f1));//кол-во записей 
  while not(EoF(f1)) do
   begin
    read(f1,rq);//считываем
    Memo1.Lines.Add('------------------------------');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Êòî:'+rq.name1);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('×òî:'+rq.chto1);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Êîãäà:'+rq.kogda);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('------------------------------');
   end;
   CloseFile(f1);//pfrhskb
 end
else ShowMessage('Нет');
end;
```

Comment: Код надо показать.

Comment: Подозреваю, что файл не закрывается, но, в любом случае хотелось бы взглянуть на код

Comment: где ваше Добавить и Обновить, которые не работают. Убедитесь, что в добавить запись в файл тоже происходит.

Comment: Файл для записи открываетcя не `reset`, а `rewrite`, так что код, вероятно, ненастоящий. Нужно показать также существенные объявления.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу код, который должен работать в D7

```
type
  TMyrec = packed record
    s: string[99];
    i: array [0 .. 99] of Byte;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject); //делает две записи
var
  f: TFileStream;
  r: TMyrec;
  i: integer;
  Flag: Word;
  filename: string;
begin
  filename := 'e:/test.db';
  if FileExists(filename) then 
    Flag := fmOpenWrite
  else
    Flag := fmCreate;
  f := TFileStream.Create(filename, Flag);
  try
    r.i[0] := 65;
    f.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
    for i := 1 to 2 do begin
      r.s := 'my long test ' + IntToStr(i);
      f.write(r, SizeOf(r));
    end;
  finally
    f.Free;
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.add('Записано');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject); // читает всё, что есть
var
  f: TFileStream;
  r: TMyrec;
begin
  f := TFileStream.Create('e:/test.db', fmOpenRead);
  try
    Memo1.Lines.add(Format('размер %d', [f.Size div SizeOf(r)]));
    while f.Size - f.Position >= SizeOf(r) do begin
      f.Read(r, SizeOf(r));
      Memo1.Lines.add(r.s);
    end;
  finally
    f.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:добавил в unit3 Кнопку('Обновить');
Спасибо за идеи.
Вот код если интересно:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Memo1.Clear;//Очищаем что-бы не было повторений
 assignFile(f1,'C:\Users\11\Desktop\ÓïðàæíåíèÿDelphi\DElaDB\HADB1.txt');//связали
  reset(f1);//открыли (кстати reset используется когда файл есть и с ним также можно записывать и считывать)
  while not(EoF(f1)) do
   begin
    read(f1,rq);//считали
    Memo1.Lines.Add('------------------------------');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Êòî:'+rq.name1);//записали
    Memo1.Lines.Add('×òî:'+rq.chto1);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Êîãäà:'+rq.kogda);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('------------------------------');
   end;
   Label1.Caption:='Çàïèñåé:'+IntToStr(FileSize(f1));//кол-во записей
   CloseFile(f1);//закрыли
end;
```